# captura de path ** angular 2 no funciona en servidor

Tags: angular, redirección, router, angular-router

Buen día,

Estoy dando soporte a una aplicación basada en angular 2 en sus primeras versiones, necesito tratar de incorporar una página de error cuando se inserta una URL que no exista en el proyecto, cuando realizo la prueba en ambiente local funciona correctamente, pero en el servidor no funciona,

lo tengo de la siguiente manera, mi app.route:

```
const appRoutes: RouterConfig = [{path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
                            {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent}];

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  ...SharedRoutes,
  ...LoginRoutes,
  ...WidgetRoutes,
  ...InicioRoutes,
  ...AuditoriaRoutes,
  ...RegistroRoutes,
  ...DocumentoRoutes,
  ...DirectorioRoutes,
  ...DominioRoutes,
  ...appRoutes
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes),
  AUTH_PROVIDERS,
  CanDeactivateGuard
];
```

y dado que en la aplicación no tienen un app.module, lo más cercano es el main.ts:

```
enableProdMode();

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms(),
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_BINDINGS

])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Traté de utilizar el HashLocationStrategy desde el main, pero tampoco funciona en mi servidor.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta algo asi:

```js
const appRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: "", redirect, redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full",
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/404", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```